Cant change return statement with Around annotation in Java Spring
I wanted to write a program like a casino at my leisure, but ran into a problem. The @Around annotation does not work as expected. I have written an example below, how to fix it?
*I have some code: *
Main
package evilcorp1win;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);
        Casino cas = context.getBean("casBean", Casino.class);
        boolean b = cas.logic();
        cas.game();

    }
}


Useful class
package evilcorp1win;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Casino {
    private int num;
    private double bet;
    private int randomNum;

    public void win() {
        System.out.println("You win " + getBet() * 2 + "$");
    }

    public void lose() {
        System.out.println("You lose " + getBet() + "$");
    }

    public int getRandomNum() {
        return randomNum;
    }

    public void setRandomNum() {
        Random random = new Random();
        this.randomNum = random.nextInt(2) + 1;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        if (num == 1 || num == 2) {
            this.num = num;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number must be either 1 or 2");
        }
    }

    public double getBet() {
        return bet;
    }

    public void setBet(double bet) {
        if (bet >= 0) {
            this.bet = bet;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bet must be non-negative");
        }
    }

    public boolean logic() {
        boolean retRes = getRandomNum() == getNum();
        return retRes;
    }

    public void game() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please bet to start playing: ");
        setBet(scan.nextDouble());
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please set number to play from 1 to 2: ");
        setNum(scan.nextInt());
        setRandomNum();
        boolean logicRes = logic();
        if (logicRes) {
            win();
        } else {
            lose();
        }
    }
}

Configuration
package evilcorp1win;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("evilcorp1win")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean("casBean")
    public Casino casBean() {
        return new Casino();
    }
}


Around aspect and pointcut to it
package evilcorp1win;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Random;

@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectAroundLog {

    @Around("evilcorp1win.Pointcuts.logicPointcut()")
    public Object aroundReturnBooleanOfLogic(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("aroundReturnBooleanOfLogic");
        Object oldRet = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println(oldRet);
        Random random = new Random();
        int randm = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        boolean newRet = false;
        if (randm == 10) {
            newRet = true;
        }
        System.out.println(newRet);
        return newRet;
    }
}

package evilcorp1win;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

public class Pointcuts {
        @Pointcut("execution(public boolean logic(..))")
        public void logicPointcut(){
        }
}

This is how my code looks like
I expected something like this:
Hello
aroundReturnBooleanOfLogic
false
false
Please bet to start playing: 50
Please set number to play from 1 to 2: 1
aroundReturnBooleanOfLogic
true
true
You win 100.0$

But i have this:
Hello
aroundReturnBooleanOfLogic
false
false
Please bet to start playing: 50
Please set number to play from 1 to 2: 1
You win 100.0$

how to fix it?
